# Irreducible polynomials: one of them must be of degree zero

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have the following definition of irreducible polynomials, given by my professor:

If $p = f * g$ , where $f, g \in F[x]$ then $degree(f) = 0 \ \ or \ \  degree(g) = 0$

And then the following sentence: it is always possible to represent a polynomial as $p = f*g$, where $deg(f) = 0$ (like this: $p = a * (a^{-1}*p)$)

I am confused, need your help. If every polynomial can be represented as such product with $deg(f) = 0$, given the definition of irreducible polynomials above, doesn't it mean every polynomial is irreducible? (I know, this is false).

F.e., I have a polynomial f = (x+2)(x-5). Well, I can represent it as $a*(a^{-1}*(x+2)(x-5)$ and say that it's irreducible as $deg(a) = 0$.

Do you see what I mean, where my problem is? 
Would you please help me to understand, what my prof. wanted to tell us?

Comment: Irreducible means that the only way to write it as a product is that one of the factors is a unit. You can of course write everything as "unit times whatever", but irreducibles, you can write in _only_ that way as a product.

Comment: Try to work out some examples to get a handle on the definition.  For example, try to prove that $x^3 - 1$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.  However, you can try to show that $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.  Play around with these examples to make sure you see what part of the definition is being used.

Comment: @Daniel, that means we talk about writing them exactly as a product of two polynomials.. I guess I see now what I overlooked.

Comment: @tylerco816, $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2+ab+b^2)$. So we can represent it as a product of exactly two polynomials and non of them is of degree 0. But x-1 must have a zero point, as well as $(x^2+ab+b^2)$. So in $\Bbb R$ they both have. Am I going in the right direction? Or I could say $x^3 = 1$, i.e. $x=1$ is a zero point for $x^3 -1$... And I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Got it.. that means I can factor it and get what I've just written above. So we have a product of two polynomials and non of them is of degree zeor. :)

Comment: And in case of $x^2 + 1$, $x = \sqrt{-1}$ i.e. x is out of $\Bbb R$, i.e. $x^2 + 1$ doesn't have zero points in $\Bbb R$, i.e. the only way to represent it as a product of two polynomials is like $a * (a^{-1} * (x^2 +1 ))$ where $deg(a) = 0$. :)

Comment: Thank you, guys!!! I'm glad Math Stackexchange exist ^^

Answer (score 1):

The confusion was resolved in comments:

- Every polynomial can be factored in a trivial way, i.e., with some of factors being   units.
- An irreducible polynomial is one that can be factored **only** in a trivial way.